# Can we run a thread inside the target function itself?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, python-multithreading

I am not sure whether we can start a thread like the one mentioned below, as I am getting an OSError: [Errno 98] error while attempting to bind on address ('0.0.0.0', 5000): address already in use .

Is the below code implementation correct.

```py
import threading

def enable_server:
      os.system('python server.py')
      t1 = threading.Thread(target=enable_server, daemon=True)
      t1.start()
```

Comment: The error is likely being generated by the code inside server.py, since none of the code shown above is calling `bind()` at all.

Comment: Doesn't this code cause an infinite regress, with each call to enable_server() starting a thread that calls enable_server() as well, leading to an infinite number of threads being spawned?  It seems like if you just want an infinite loop, you don't need threads at all, so much as a `while True:`

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure whether we can start a thread like the one mentioned below,

Technically, yes you can, and the error you receive is probably reflective of that.

> as I am getting an OSError: [Errno 98] error while attempting to bind on address ('0.0.0.0', 5000): address already in use

If the error arises from the code presented at all, then it must come from `os.system('python server.py')`.  In that case, `server.py` must try to set up a socket listening on port 5000.  It is entirely plausible that it fails the second time, when your code relaunches the server immediately after it terminates, because by default there is a short but observable delay after a TCP or UDP port is closed during which the system will prevent it from being opened again.

You should be able to confirm that the threading has nothing to do with that by rewriting the code without threads, as it should have been written in the first place, and observing (I predict) the same behavior.  For example:

```
while True:
    os.system('python server.py')
```